# PHPStorm, unit testing the current class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to migrate from NetBeans to PHPStorm and the thing I cannot figure out is: how do I run my test suite for the current class (which ever that might be) without creating a run configuration for each class separately?

In NetBeans, you can run your entire suite with Alt+F6 or run the current class with just F6. This enables you to run just the tests you need and not your entire suite all the time which is obviously a time saver.

I cannot figure out how to do this in PHPStorm without creating a new run configuration for each and every class in the project which I obviously do not want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First You have to tell PHPStorm where do You store your tests:

1. Settings->Directories mark your tests folder as tests
2. Configure Settings->PHP->PHPUnit
3. Right click on any test in Your test dir and choose "Run" it will create test configuration for this particular test file on the fly.

You can even right click on a single test method and choose "Run" (or Debug),
Same for any test folder (if you have nested tests directories).

Comment: Yes, I know about that, the key point here is to create a Run Configuration (say, "PHPUnit current class") and enable me to run it for ANY class in my tree. So, testing any class with one run configuration?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. PHPStorm just creates on the fly run configuration for method/file/folder and runs PHPUnit with that configuration. Notice that it keeps only 5 last configurations so it does not do a big mess.

Comment: I see. So, the workflow is that I run the tests once, it creates the (temporary) run configuration which I get to invoke with F6 until happy? OK, seems reasonable now I know the run configs are temporary, did not notice it says "Save configuration". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This thread helped me a lot and I was thankful for [Jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27334830/2683059) however I had to do additional digging so I thought I would try to take it a bit further:

1. File > settings > Directories

   - select any directories containing tests (perhaps
     yourprojectroot/tests) and click Mark as: Tests
   - note that you can repeat this step if you have
     multiple directories containing tests and that
     the selection will include sub directories so no
     worries.
2. File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP

   - Make sure your php language level and CLI interpreter are setup right
3. File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > PHPUnit

   - assuming your using composer select *use Composer autoloader* and set the path to `yourprojectroot/vendor/autoload.php`
   - or you can select *Path to phpunit.phar* and navigate to `vendor/bin/phpunit`, then check the box next to *Default bootstrap file* and make that the path to `vendor/autoload.php`
4. Open any phpunit test file in the editor and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> to run it

   - Not sure about the key bind for mac but if you click Run > Run...  that will work also, and it will tell you the keybind in the submenu

**Additional Tips**: Since posting this and using the feature I learned a few more helpful things and thought I would just add them here:

- In the project file explorer if you select any test directory or test
  file and do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> it will run
  that file or all test files in the directory.
- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> - will re-run whatever test you ran
  last, so if you are doing TDD and previously executed the test and
  you are working in the class being tested you can make a change and
  just press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> after each change and it
  re-runs the previously run test, no need to select the test to re-run
  it.